# При наведении на кнопку таблица не должна сдвигаться

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/4GGxA/

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    background: url('images/background.jpg') 50% 50% fixed;
}
#wrapper {
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 850px;
}
button {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 5px 5px 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
button:hover {
    padding: 1px;
}
#hidden {
    clear: left;
}
table {
    color: #666;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    background: #fff;
    width: 800px;
}
table td {
    padding: 5px 20px;
    border: 2px solid #bbb;
}
table td:hover {
    background: #eee;
}
.info {
    margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="info">
        <button id="add">+</button>
        <button id="hidden">-</button>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Составление плана по выполнению задачи. Корректировка плана заказчиком по его письменной просьбе, или в случаях изменения им технического задания.' AS `Составление плана по выполнению задачи. Корректировка плана заказчиком по его письменной просьбе, или в случаях изменения им технического</td>
                <td>150.00</td>
                <td>10</td>
                <td>1500.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4">Модерниза́ция компью́тера (апгрейд; upgrade) — обычно по отношению к персональному компьютеру — замена отдельных компонентов компьютера на более совершенные или мощные. Современные персональные компьютеры построены по модульной системе, что позволяет проводить модернизацию, и получать более производительный компьютер, сохраняя инвестиции.</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Есть такая разметка со стилями. Проблема в том, что при наведении на кнопку "+" она увеличивается и таблица сдвигается вправо, хотя предполагается, что такого не должно быть. С кнопкой "-" все нормально. Их отличия в том, что кнопка "+" плавающая, но я все равно не знаю как исправить.
PS. И еще - почему при задании border-radius: 5px для table углы у нее не скругляются?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/9NTSp/

Одновременно с паддингом меняете маргин.
Чтобы не было проблем со скруглением, есть предложение отказаться от таблиц в пользу блоков. Иначе придется скруглять углы ОТДЕЛЬНО для каждой "неправильной" ячейки.

Comment: Как все легко оказалось, спасибо большой!